# MySQL query to return rows that are equal to or greater than a certain date, where the date is separated in year, month and day columns

Tags: sql, mysql

A MySQL table EMPLOYEE has columns (beginyear, beginmonth, beginday, empid) all of type int.

What's a correct query to return all rows that are equal to or greater than the date 2009/8/13?  That's year, month, day.

A query such as this is incorrect because it wouldn't return rows that contained dates such as 2009/9/1 (filtered out by beginday >=13 in where clause below) or 2010/1/14.

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE
where beginyear >= 2009
  and beginmonth >= 8
  and beginday >=13
```

Assume I can't make any changes to the schema and that I have to create some sort of query from JDBC to get the results.

Comment: That is bad design. If it's within your power, put the whole date in a single field..

Comment: Absolutely agree about the bad design.  But I cannot change it and need to work with what I'm given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could do with your bad situation of three different fields:

```
select *, concat(beginyear, '-',beginmonth,'-',beingday) as full_date 
  FROM TABLE 
   WHERE CONCAT(beginyear, '-',beginmonth,'-',beingday) >= '2009-08-13'
```

MySql's notion of a datetime expression is sort of peculiar, you might want to wrap the concat with a `date()` function to normalize it.

Comment: +1: My thoughts too, but I'd go one further to encapsulate the `CONCAT` in `STR_TO_DATE(concat(beginyear, '-',beginmonth,'-',beingday), '%Y-%m-%d')` - because date formats aren't consistent.  What sucks is that indexes on the three columns can't be used...

Comment: I ran the query "select *, concat(beginyear, '-',beginmonth,'-',beginday) as full_date from employee where full_date >= '2009-08-13'" and I received "Error code 1054, SQL state 42S22: Unknown column 'full_date' in 'where clause'"

Comment: @Eunice: See update - can't reference a column alias in the WHERE clause

Comment: thanks for editing my sloppy work, OMG Ponies -- glad to hear it all worked out, Eunice